# The package cucumber.api is accessible from more than one module: cucumber.core, cucumber.java, cucumber.junit

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I have made a runner file. Inside that runner file, I have written code:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features="loginTest.feature"
    )
public class loginRun {
}
```

I am getting error saying "The package cucumber.api is accessible from more than one module: cucumber.core, cucumber.java, cucumber.junit"

Comment: Are you using java9?

Comment: What build tool are you using? Maven, Gradle?

Comment: @mpkorstanje yup, I am using java 9

Comment: @ThomasSundberg I am not using any build tool, I have used External jarscobertura-2.1.1
cucumber-core-2.1.0
cucumber-java-2.1.0
cucumber-junit-2.1.0
gherkin-5.0.0
cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.6
junit4-4.8.2
mockito-all-2.0.2-beta
selenium-server-standalone-3.7.0

Comment: @ManiRaj then you should definitely provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If you don't use a build tool it gets a lot, and really a lot, more complicated. Take a look at the Ant build file in getting started sample for Cucumber-JVM. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton/blob/master/build.xml
It will show you what you need to include.

Comment: Echoing @ThomasSundberg, what is on your classpath (i.e. system environment variable)? I don't have cucumber.core on mine.